# Get transferred/resources size and DOMContentLoaded/Load time from devTools network metrics

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance-testing, puppeteer

I am building a web application named UXChecker which works similary to [website.grader.com](https://website.grader.com/) but with a number of differences.

After the user sends URL from frontend via API to backend, I want to crawl this URL and do UX measurement. I will be checking buttons, SEO, responsivity, etc. as well as **checking network metrics** saying what is **the total size** of the web (Mb) and **how fast** did it load. I decided to do it in Node.js using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Is there a way how to get "total page size" (resources size) and "load time" (or at least DOMContentLoad) metrics?

[image]

If not, could you recommend a different library or code snippets, please?

So far I have tried:

```
const perfEntries = JSON.parse(
    await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(performance.getEntries()))
);
```

I have counted all transferSizes but the number is not even close to the numbers from network devTools tab. 
After that I tried:

```
    let performanceMetrics = await page._client.send('Performance.getMetrics');
```

which gave me "DOMContentLoaded" among the other metrics. But this number was different from the value in the network tab. I wasn't able to get totalSize (resources size) of the web.

---

My Puppeteer code (you can test by running `node example.js`):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

    // setting width and height
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 780,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    });

    // going to URL
    await page.goto("http://www.cupcakeipsum.com/", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });


    // performance entries available
    const perfEntries = JSON.parse(
        await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(performance.getEntries()))
    );

    // performance test
    // total size of the website:
    totalSize = () => {
        let totalSize = 0;
        perfEntries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.transferSize > 0) {
                totalSize += entry.transferSize;
            }
        });
        return totalSize;
    }
    console.log("==== Total size ====")
    console.log(totalSize());

    // performance metrics
    console.log("==== Devtools: Performance.getMetrics ====");
    let performanceMetrics = await page._client.send('Performance.getMetrics');
    console.log(performanceMetrics.metrics);


    await browser.close();
})();
```

Is there a way to measure these metrics, please? I will be thankful for every help and tips.

Comment: Check these [1](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr), [2](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3372)

Comment: @Eldar thank you. Although I was not able to solve this issue. I just wanted to get the same results as lighthouse can get for me. Nevermind, thank you anyway!